# Why does my Rcpp code give unexpected all integer value output?

Tags: c++, r, matrix, distance, rcpp

Given a data matrix X, I want to compute the pairwise distance matrix between any two rows of X. I have the following code, which came from slightly adjusting the code [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-distance-matrix/).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace Rcpp;
// generic function for l1_distance
template <typename InputIterator1, typename InputIterator2>
inline double l1_distance(InputIterator1 begin1, InputIterator1 end1, 
                            InputIterator2 begin2) {
   double rval = 0;
   InputIterator1 it1 = begin1;
   InputIterator2 it2 = begin2;
   while (it1 != end1) {
      double d1 = *it1++;
      double d2 = *it2++;
      rval += abs(d1 - d2);
   }
   return rval;  
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix rcpp_l1_distance(NumericMatrix mat) {

   // allocate the matrix we will return
   NumericMatrix rmat(mat.nrow(), mat.nrow());
   for (int i = 0; i < rmat.nrow(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
         NumericMatrix::Row row1 = mat.row(i);
         NumericMatrix::Row row2 = mat.row(j);
         double d = l1_distance(row1.begin(), row1.end(), row2.begin());
         rmat(i,j) = d;
         rmat(j,i) = d;
      }
   }
   return rmat;
}
```

The problem is that this code returns a matrix of all integer values. The integer values seem to be positively correlated with the distance values that I want, which makes it more confusing. I also computed a pairwise l2 distance matrix and pairwise normalized l1 distance (dividing l1 distance between two rows by the sum of their l1-norm) matrix, and they both behaved as expected.

Can someone tell me which part did I make a mistake?

You can do the following to get the weird result

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("distance.cpp") #the file containing the cpp code above
X = matrix(rnorm(16), 4, 4)
rcpp_l1_distance(X)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just as a side note, you could also use the `stats::dist` function with `method = "manhattan"`.

Comment: Just making sure. I can do that in the C++ script up there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling your code gives me these warnings:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('Desktop/mat.cpp')
mat.cpp:16:15: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
      rval += abs(d1 - d2);
              ^
mat.cpp:16:15: note: use function 'std::abs' instead
      rval += abs(d1 - d2);
              ^~~
              std::abs
mat.cpp:16:15: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
      rval += abs(d1 - d2);
              ^
mat.cpp:30:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'l1_distance<Rcpp::MatrixRow<14>::iterator, Rcpp::MatrixRow<14>::iterator>' requested here
      double d = l1_distance(row1.begin(), row1.end(), row2.begin());
                 ^
mat.cpp:16:15: note: use function 'std::abs' instead
      rval += abs(d1 - d2);
              ^~~
              std::abs
2 warnings generated.
```

... hinting that `abs` is for integers, see [this help page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/?kw=abs), you can use [fabs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fabs/?kw=fabs) instead, or [std::abs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/), or you can use sugar's `operator-`, `abs` and `sum`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix rcpp_l1_distance(NumericMatrix mat) {

  // allocate the matrix we will return
  NumericMatrix rmat(mat.nrow(), mat.nrow());
  for (int i = 0; i < rmat.nrow(); i++) {
    NumericMatrix::Row row1 = mat.row(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      rmat(j,i) = rmat(i,j) = sum( abs(row1 - mat.row(j) )) ;
    }
  }
  return rmat;
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, you want to enable warnings generation from your compiler which help to catch problems like this one.

Comment: Thank you both a lot! I definitely have to enable warnings for the compiler.